# How to avoid getting empty fields in a databound combo box?

Tags: vb.net

How to avoid getting empty fields in a databound combo box?

Comment: do you have a code sample you're having problems with?

Comment: Actually the combo box bound to my table in database also gets the fileds which are empty.  I wish it adds only that fields which have data.

Comment: @user415037: Are the values empty strings or NULL? Either way you can add a check to only pull in values that either have a length > 0 or are not NULL. The details of that will depend on the data types you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a List(of ..) to hold the values of your ComboBox text then you can try:

```
Dim idList1 As New List(Of String)
idList1.Add("1")
idList1.Add("2")
idList1.Add("3")
idList1.Add("1")

Dim idList2 As New List(Of String)
idList2 = idList1.Distinct().ToList()
```

The `idList.Distinct()` pulls out the unique values. So that if you were to print each item in `idList2` you would just get ("1","2","3"). Do this first before you create the contents of the ComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't filter the data you recieve before it gets to you, you can create a new `DataView` and apply your own filter and use that as your datasource.

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim table As DataTable = New DataTable
table.Columns.Add("id", GetType(System.Int32))
table.Columns.Add("name", GetType(System.String))
i = (i + 1)
table.Rows.Add(i, "hello")
i = (i + 1)
table.Rows.Add(i, string.Empty)
i = (i + 1)
table.Rows.Add(i, "what")
i = (i + 1)
table.Rows.Add(i, DBNull.Value)
i = (i + 1)
table.Rows.Add(i, "derp")
Dim view As DataView = New DataView(table)
view.RowFilter = "name <> ''"
Me.comboBox1.ValueMember = "id"
Me.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "name"
Me.comboBox1.DataSource = view
```

`RowFilter` takes a sql-style where clause for selecting matches. this includes only the 3 good values in the combobox.

selecting only the data you need in the first place is still a better idea.